# how to check ActiveMQ queue size from message listener

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using message listener for performing some actions on activeMQ queues
I want to check size of queue while performing.
I am using below logic but it works outside listener.
Any suggestion?

```
public class TestClass {
    MessageConsumer consumerTransformation;
    MessageListener listenerObjectTransformation;
    public static void main(String []args) throws JMSException {
        ActiveMQModel activeMQModelObject = new ActiveMQModel();
        //String subject = "TRANSFORMATION_QUEUE";
        String subject = "IMPORT_QUEUE";
         //consumerTransformation = activeMQModelObject.getActiveMQConsumer(subject);

          // Here we set the listener to listen to all the messages in the queue
          //listenerObjectTransformation = new TransformationMessageListener();
          //consumerTransformation.setMessageListener(listenerObjectTransformation);
          boolean isQueueEmpty = activeMQModelObject.isMessageQueueEmpty(subject);
          System.out.println("Size " + isQueueEmpty);
    }
    /*private class TransformationMessageListener implements MessageListener {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message messagearg) {
            System.out.println("test....");
        }
    }*/
}
```

What is way to  check activeMQ queue size from message listener

Answer (score 0):

The JMS API does not define methods for checking Queue size or other metrics from a client, the API is meant to decouple the clients from any server administration and from each other.  A sender has no awareness of the receivers that might or might not be there and the receiver is unaware of who might be producing or if there is anything to consume at that given moment.  By using the asynchronous listener you are subscribing for content either currently available or content yet to be produced.

You can in some cases make us of the [JMX metrics](https://activemq.apache.org/jmx) that are available from the server in your code but this is not good practice.